# STM32: An internal error occurred during: "Launching GPIO_IOToggle (6)". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm following the [STM32 Step by Step guide: Tools Installation](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32StepByStep:Step1_Tools_installation#Download_STM32CubeL4_Firmware_package) (yes, part 1 of the guide), but translated to the [STM32756-EVAL](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/data_brief/f9/7d/36/c3/33/b7/40/8e/DM00172858.pdf/files/DM00172858.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00172858.pdf) context (The STM32756-EVAL is a Evaluation board with STM32F756NG MCU). I am in the process of building and debugging the example file, which I have not modified. The address of the specific example file I am using is

> Username\STM32Cube\Repository\STM32Cube_FW_F7_V1.17.0\Projects\STM32756G_EVAL\Examples\GPIO\GPIO_IOToggle

The instructions on the tutorial, based on my understanding, are to build the file and debug it.

[image]

When I start the debugging process, I am returned with this error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching GPIO_IOToggle (6)".
> java.lang.NullPointerException

This resembles a Java error but I am running my code in C. Furthermore, according to the IDE, the program is already running.

[image]

According to the readme file for the example program (I do not know whether this is relevant),

> In order to make the program work, you must do the following :
>
> - Open your preferred toolchain
> - Rebuild all files and load your image into target memory
> - Run the example
>   I have completed the "rebuild all files" element but am unable to locate the built image within my directory.

Please let me know if more information is required, this is my first incursion into STM32 and I was not expecting the first tutorial of the STM32 to be the cause of this amount of confusion. Thanks for your patience, I am very fresh to STM32 embedded programming.

Comment: Is the program running on you hardware? Error message is related to the eclipse/Cube IDE itself. Are there any other outputs in the IDE console?